# Mexico stamp date not legible

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I traveled to Cancun on July 3 , 2017 from Miami, but the date on the stamp is not legible . I have tried taking pictures of it and magnify it but it doesn’t work I’m in a legal situation in which I need to prove that I was traveling that date.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Willeke I think that the OPs questions is how does he prove that he traveled from Miami to Cancun on July 3, 2017

Comment: @PeterM, that is not unlikely but they can search for other methods to get the stamp readable, or something else again. It does not cost to make it a real question and not have us guessing.

Comment: Is checking the flight details not an easier method?

Comment: @JamesPD Checking flight details proves that the flight made the trip to Cancun.  It doesn't prove that the OP was on that flight.

Comment: One can always make a FOIA request to CBP for travel records. It costs $25 and takes a month or so. A non-immigrant might find travel records at the I-94 web site.